# Laravel dynamic form building with JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, laravel-5

I am working on a Laravel app, I have a form build in to my javascript, I am dynamically trying to set the action and method and post form based on the value of my drop down selection.

Form Code:

```
function _RemoveForm(url){
    var delete_form = '{{ Form::open(array("method" => "GET", "id" => "_RemoveForm")) }} {{ Form::close() }}';
    return delete_form;
}
```

When I post this form using form.submit() in js, I am able to route/redirect to edit or index but when I post this form to destroy which requires method to be 'post' it shows

```
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68:
```

Is it possible to create form like this and post to actions? Or should I try some other approach.

EDIT:

Form is created from string like this:

```
var form = "{{ Form::open(array("method" => "GET", "id" => "_RemoveForm")) }} {{ Form::close() }}";
    $("body").append(form);

    form = $("#_RemoveForm");

    form.attr('action', url);

    if(method == 'delete'){
        form.attr('method', 'post');
        form.append('<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">');
    }

    form.submit();
```

This is all done in on change event of a dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

Is the CSRF token sent with your request? e.g.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });

<meta name="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```